# docker-machine+digital ocean: How to mount volumes?

Tags: docker, web-deployment, digital-ocean, docker-volume

I'm using volumes to persist data between container restarts. I've tested this on my dev machine and it works fine. I successfully deployed my application onto Digital Ocean using docker-machine but the data doesn't persist after container restarts (e.g `docker-compose down` followed by `docker-compose up`).

Using volumes with docker-machine should work, right? How can I check if the volumes has mounted on my remote machine (e.g. DO)? `docker volume ls` shows volumes mounted on my local machine but I have no idea how to check for the volumes mounted on the remote machine.

The operating systems for my development and remote machines are both Ubuntu 16.04.

The relevant db/volume bits from my docker-compose file (I, of course, have other services but I omitted them for brevity):

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.5
    volumes:
      -db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

 volumes:
 db:
```

Comment: Docker volumes are used to retain your data between container-instances. However, you could remove volumes since containers can write down data on writable layers and it will be available when you restart your same container. Try using named containers with --name "named-container" when creating your container or you can use container-name in docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I misunderstood your question. 
 Now to answer : the problem that you are facing is because of **docker-compose down** , instead of that you can try **docker-compose stop**

For more information about docker-compose

```
Commands:
  build              Build or rebuild services
  create             Create services
  down               Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes
  start              Start services
  stop               Stop services
  up                 Create and start containers
```

Comment: So when you are executing #docker-compose down , it is removing volumes also.... docker-compose version on your machine and on remote machine might be different which is causing this issue.